# Insert text in CKEditors using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I tried to run below code it click into CKEditor but not type in it. The test also doesn't fail either.

```
WebElement certificationScope =  driver.findElement(By.id("cke_auditStageOneRpt_iaqgCertStageOneRpt_proposedCertScope"));
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
JavascriptExecutor certificationScope1 = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
certificationScope1.executeScript(longText, certificationScope);
```

Comment: You are executing JavaScript for CKEditor ? Why just do not send keys by selenium ?

Comment: Send keys works but take lot of time to enter text. I am trying to enter long text. like really long to test some forms. Every form has 5-6 ckeditor fields to enter.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May i ask how big is text and how long is take to send it by selenium ?

Comment: Here is the text: it takes around 30-40 seconds but I have like 10 field to send this text in.Its not letting me paste in here as it has too big file around 8000 characters

Comment: I see, well this is may be this time is normal for selenium. And JS may be is a option. But to past text to CKEditor, it doesn't really required to be focused ( Except may be if you use inline version.) I guess problem in your JS, may i see your JS code ?